# In-Phase and Quadrature components of low-pass equivalent of a band-pass signal?

Tags: digital-communications, hilbert-transform, quadrature

I was wondering what is the physical meaning of **IN-PHASE** and **QUADRATURE** components?
In the context of *low-pass* equivalent of *band-pass* signals.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

i will call the *bandpass signal*:

$$\begin{align}
 y(t) &= \Re \Big\{ (x(t) + j\hat{x}(t)) \, e^{j \omega_0 t} \Big\} \\
\\
      &= x(t) \cos(\omega_0 t) - \hat{x}(t) \sin(\omega_0 t)  \\
\end{align}$$

the complex-valued $x(t) + j \hat{x}(t)$ is the low-pass equivalent to the *bandpass signal*.

the real part $x(t)$ is the *in-phase component* and the imaginary part $\hat{x}(t)$ is the *quadrature component*.

the in-phase and quadrature components **may** have nothing to do with each other and then the spectrum of the low-pass equivalent is arbitrary with no symmetry implied.

if $\hat{x}(t)=0$, the low-pass equivalent is purely real and spectrum of it has *hilbert symmetry* with the real and imaginary parts.

if the in-phase and quadrature components are related by the *Hilbert Transform*,

$$\begin{align}
 \hat{x}(t) &= \mathscr{H} \Big\{ x(t) \Big\} \\
\\
            &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{t-\epsilon} x(u) \frac{1}{t-u} du \ + \ \int\limits_{t+\epsilon}^{+\infty} x(u) \frac{1}{t-u} du \\
\end{align}$$

then the spectrum of the low-pass equivalent is zero for all negative frequencies and has only a positive-frequency component.